# jQuery: How to re-count and re-name elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of table rows and these tr's have numbered classes for some reason (leg-1, leg-2 etc). It is already possible to delete a single tr from within this context.

After deleting a tr I need to rename the remaining tr's.

Example: 
I have

```
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
```

Now I delete leg-2. Remaining are:

```
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
```

Now I want to rename the remaining tr's, so that it's back to leg-1 and leg-2.

How can this be done??

Thx for any help!

---

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that it can have more than one tr with class "leg-1", "leg-2" ... So the right starting example would be

```
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
```

Now when I delete leg-2 , both of the tr's with class="leg-3" have to be renamed to be class="leg-2". ..

Sorry I didn't mention this earlier!!

**SEE IT IN ACTION**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lynkb22n/2/

Comment: Why are you using class-names to uniquely identify elements? That's what the `id` is for.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do by renaming class, it sounds like a XY problem. You'd have better to explain why would you need that?

Comment: Manipulating dom will trigger re -layout of the page, if your doing it often it will slow down your page. I suggest you to think for another approach. Perhaps if you can explain what is it that you're trying to achieve, we can think of a better solution :)

Comment: ok, thank you for all of your solutions! I forgot to mention that it can have more than one tr with class "leg-1", "leg-2" ...
So starting example would be
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>

Now when I delete leg-2 , both of the tr's with class="leg-3" have to be renamed to be class="leg-2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Updated

Based on your comment below and your updated question, here is an updated solution.

```
var removed = $(".leg-2"),
    siblings = removed.nextAll(), // affect only next siblings to removed element
    pos = ""; // store current number after "leg-"

removed.remove(); // remove element

siblings.each(function (k) {
    $(this).removeClass(function (i, key) {
        pos = key.split("-")[1]; // update number after "leg-"
        return (key.match(/\bleg-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("leg-" + (pos - 1)); // add "leg-" plus new position
});
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umrm4x9p/).

---

You can use `.removeClass()` with `.match()` to remove class starts with `leg` and then add class `leg` plus `tr`'s index using `.addClass()`.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3ww4yn/).

```
$("tr").each(function (k) {
    k++;
    $(this).removeClass(function (i, key) {
        return (key.match(/\bleg-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("leg-" + k);
});
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your solution so far! 
I forgot to mention that it can have more than one tr with class "leg-1", "leg-2" ... So the right starting example would be

<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>

Now when I delete leg-2 , both of the tr's with class="leg-3" have to be renamed to be class="leg-2". .. .:-/ Sorry I didn't mention this earlier!!

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi I am glad to hear so :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, at its most straightforward:

```
$('tr').each(function(i) {
  // looking for a class-name that starts with (follows a
  // word-boundary: \b) leg- followed by one or more numbers (\d+)
  // followed by another word-boundary:
  var matchedClass = this.className.match(/\bleg-\d+\b/);
  // if a match exists:
  if (matchedClass) {
    // set the node's className to the same className after replacing
    // the found leg-X class name with the string of 'leg-' plus the
    // index of the current element in the collection plus one:
    this.className = this.className.replace(matchedClass[0], 'leg-' + (i + 1));
  }
});
```

```js
$('tr').each(function(i) {
  var matchedClass = this.className.match(/\bleg-\d+\b/);
  // if a match exists:
  if (matchedClass) {
    this.className = this.className.replace(matchedClass[0], 'leg-' + (i + 1));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="leg-2323523">
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="leg-2323523">
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="leg-2323523">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="leg-2323523">
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using an `id` is somewhat easier, since we don't need to preserve pre-existing concurrent `id`s, as we do with classes:

```
// selects all <tr> elements, sets their `id` property
// using the anonymous function available within prop():
$('tr').prop('id', function (i) {
  // i: the index amongst the collection of <tr> elements:
  return 'leg-' + (i+1);
});
```

```js
$('tr').prop('id', function (i) {
  return 'leg-' + (i+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If the index/row-number is simply to be available to JavaScript, then you could just as easily use the native `rowIndex` property available to all `HTMLTableRowElement`s:

```
// selects <tr> elements, binds the 'mouseenter' event-handler:
$('tr').on('mouseenter', function() {
  // logs the HTMLTableRowElement rowIndex property
  // to the console:
  console.log(this.rowIndex);
});
```

```js
$('tr').on('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log(this.rowIndex);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expression Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: ok, thank you for your solution so far! 
I forgot to mention that it can have more than one tr with class "leg-1", "leg-2" ... So the right starting example would be

<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>

Now when I delete leg-2 , both of the tr's with class="leg-3" have to be renamed to be class="leg-2". .. .:-/ Sorry I didn't mention this earlier!!

Comment: Then you may need to edit your question to include the relevant details, since this 'row-count' appears to be something other than a row-count. Given the answers you've got to your original question, however, I'd suggest asking another question and *explicitly stating* your requirements (otherwise it looks like you've arbitrarily made your question different and invalidated the posted answers).

Comment: +1 ok, your solution wasn't exactly what I was looking for (cause I didn't asked the complete question... shame on me), but it was helpful anyway!!

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have helped, if only in a small and incomplete manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will re-name the class:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
$("#click").click(function(){
 reorder();
});

   
   });
function reorder(){
   $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function(index) {
console.log($(this).attr('class','leg-'+(index+1)));//avaoid starting fron 0
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="leg-1"><td>a1</td></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"><td>a2</td></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"><td>a3</td></tr>
<tr class="leg-7"><td>a4</td></tr><!--after click on button class will become class="leg-4" -->
<tr class="leg-8"><td>a5</td></tr><!--after click on button class will become class="leg-5" -->
</table>

<button id="click">CliCk</button>
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your solution so far! 
I forgot to mention that it can have more than one tr with class "leg-1", "leg-2" ... So the right starting example would be

<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-1"></tr>
<tr class="leg-2"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>
<tr class="leg-3"></tr>

Now when I delete leg-2 , both of the tr's with class="leg-3" have to be renamed to be class="leg-2". .. .:-/ Sorry I didn't mention this earlier!!